# Sending a POST array and memory leak

Tags: php, arrays, post, memory

When sending an HTTP POST array of text data, for example from a web page with an HTML form and text fields, if we use as the name property of the fields the following array `url_alias[id]` with id being a positive integer, we receive with PHP:

```
[url_alias] => Array
    (
        [2644] => url-of-product-ref-123
        [1] => url-of-product-ref-224
    )
```

how will the server (Apache Linux, for example) handle the POST data? Will it internally prepare an array with 2645 indexes, with a null pointer to all indexes except the index: 1 and the index: 2644, or will it do in other, optimized way? Is the format above correct in terms of efficiency - it is very comfortable for PHP programming, but I am afraid of memory leakages or something.

Comment: No it won't prepare an array with 2645 indexes.... PHP arrays are hashmaps, not traditional arrays; this hashmap will have have just 2 indexed entries, one for `1` and one for `2644`

Comment: 1 - In php settings, you have a POST max setting, which limits the amount of data that a client is allowed to send via POST. 2 - If you allow enough space, you can send it, but you have to build it yourself in the ajax/http request, PHP wont automatically fill 2644 entries for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From PHP [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

> An array in PHP is actually an ordered map. A map is a type that associates values to keys. This type is optimized for several different uses; it can be treated as an array, list (vector), hash table (an implementation of a map), dictionary, collection, stack, queue, and probably more. As array values can be other arrays, trees and multidimensional arrays are also possible.

In your example it holds only two keys with one value assigned to each.

The manual has examples on how arrays in PHP behave. For example, if you set up the following array:

```
$array = array(
         "a",
         "b",
    6 => "c",
         "d",
);
```

They keys assigned will be `0`, `1`, `6` and `7`:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "b"
  [6]=>
  string(1) "c"
  [7]=>
  string(1) "d"
}
```

Please read the manual to learn more.

**UPDATE**

You are also asking how arrays are sent over HTTP. They (arrays) are not. According to W3C specification defined [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html):

> The form data set is then encoded according to the content type specified by the `enctype` attribute of the FORM element.

Each `enctype` has it's own rules too long and extensive to be listed here. Read it there if you wish. The thing is, when PHP receives the encoded data, it automatically decodes indexed form variable names.

So, to wrap it up, the form data is encoded, sent to PHP and the decoding process is on PHP side.

Comment: Well, I am a little confused here. It seems very reasonable, but my question was about HTML itself. I mean, you can read it with PHP, Python, C#,.... If you write name[id], how the data is sent in the HTTP protocol? The PHP interpretation I understand from your excellent response, but still with the doubt about the HTTP transfer itself.

Comment: You could go one step further and include a quick example of the encoded data - the general rules are complex, but the example is as simple as saying that standard form encoding produces `url_alias[2644]=abc&url_alias[1]=cde`, which is decoded by PHP as though you had written `$_POST['url_alias'][2644] = 'abc'; $_POST['url_alias'][1] = 'cde';`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I understand at last why when using Curl the data is sent by POST but you format the data as if it were GET like  ?var1=data1&var2=data2,... etc.